# Workflow overdue mails even after workflow completion.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, 2016

I am getting workflow overdue mails, even after the workflow is completed.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your workflow

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are some previous versions of the workflow in the list/ library are running (in progress).

List/Library Settings -> Workflow Settings

Remove all previous workflows which you do not need anymore by clicking on **Remove, block, or restore a workflow** option.

After that, compare the results. Check if the overdue reminder is stopped.